# How can I improve my detection efficiency when flann?

Tags: python, performance, opencv, computer-vision, orb

I'm trying to improve the speed of my object detection. I'm using `OpenCV` and `ORB` brute force keypoint matching.

I've got 30 seconds for `keypoint_detection` to run and at the moment it's taking about 23 seconds. This is fine for now with 74 images, but that number is likely to increase.

So far I've;

- Reduced my search area down to the absolute minimum
- Refined my 74 images down to the absolute minimum size possible

I tried pre-processing to remove some of the clutter from the matching but it impacted my ability to find a successful match dramatically.

I've also tried;

- SIF, SURF, MatchTemplate, Canny and a few other methods. ORB brute force is my best match by a significant margin.

This is my exact working code, not pseudo-code and not an MVP as I didn't think it would make sense presenting a cut down version of the code I'm looking to speed up.

Is there any way to improve the efficiency of my code?

```
  import cv2 as cv
  import os
  import glob
  import pyautogui as py
  from time import sleep
  from windowcapture import WindowCapture
  from vision import Vision

  # Change the working directory to the folder this script is in.
  os.chdir(r'C:\test')

  avoid = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\test\*.png")

  def loadImages(directory):
    # Intialise empty array
    image_list = []
    # Add images to array
    for i in directory:
        img = cv.imread(i, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        image_list.append((img, i))
    return image_list

  # initialize the WindowCapture class
  wincap = WindowCapture()

  def keypoint_detection(image_list):
      counter = 0
      for i in image_list:
          counter += 1       
          needle_img = i[0]

          # load image to find
          objectToFind = Vision(needle_img)
          # get an updated image of the screen
          keypoint_haystack = wincap.get_haystack()
          # crop the image
          x, w, y, h = [600,700,20,50]
          keypoint_haystack = keypoint_haystack[y:y+h, x:x+w]

          kp1, kp2, matches, match_points = objectToFind.match_keypoints(keypoint_haystack, sliced_name, min_match_count=30)
          match_image = cv.drawMatches(objectToFind.needle_img, kp1, keypoint_haystack, kp2, matches, None)

          if match_points:
              # find the center point of all the matched features
              center_point = objectToFind.centeroid(match_points)
              # account for the width of the needle image that appears on the left
              center_point[0] += objectToFind.needle_w
              # drawn the found center point on the output image
              match_image = objectToFind.draw_crosshairs(match_image, [center_point])
            
              sleep(3)
              break

  while(True):
      ships_to_avoid = loadImages(avoid)
      keypoint_detection(ships_to_avoid)
```

WindowCapture Class

```
import numpy as np
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con

class WindowCapture:

    # properties
    w = 0
    h = 0
    hwnd = None
    cropped_x = 0
    cropped_y = 0
    offset_x = 0
    offset_y = 0

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, window_name=None):
        # find the handle for the window we want to capture.
        # if no window name is given, capture the entire screen
        if window_name is None:
            self.hwnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
        else:
            self.hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
            if not self.hwnd:
                raise Exception('Window not found: {}'.format(window_name))

        # get the window size
        window_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(self.hwnd)
        self.w = window_rect[2] - window_rect[0]
        self.h = window_rect[3] - window_rect[1]

        # account for the window border and titlebar and cut them off
        border_pixels = 0
        titlebar_pixels = 5
        self.w = self.w - border_pixels
        self.h = self.h - titlebar_pixels - border_pixels
        self.cropped_x = border_pixels
        self.cropped_y = titlebar_pixels

        # set the cropped coordinates offset so we can translate screenshot
        # images into actual screen positions
        self.offset_x = window_rect[0] + self.cropped_x
        self.offset_y = window_rect[1] + self.cropped_y

    def get_haystack(self):

        # get the window image data
        wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.hwnd)
        dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
        cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
        dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.w, self.h)
        cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
        cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (self.w, self.h), dcObj, (self.cropped_x, self.cropped_y), win32con.SRCCOPY)

        # convert the raw data into a format opencv can read
        # dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, 'debug.bmp')
        signedIntsArray = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')
        img.shape = (self.h, self.w, 4)

        # free resources
        dcObj.DeleteDC()
        cDC.DeleteDC()
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.hwnd, wDC)
        win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
        img = img[...,:3]
        img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
        return img

    @staticmethod
    def list_window_names():
        def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
            if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
                print(hex(hwnd), win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
        win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

    # translate a pixel position on a screenshot image to a pixel position on the screen.
    # pos = (x, y)
    def get_screen_position(self, pos):
        return (pos[0] + self.offset_x, pos[1] + self.offset_y)
```

Vision Class

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


class Vision:
    # properties
    needle_img = None
    needle_w = 0
    needle_h = 0

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, needle_img_path):
        self.needle_img = needle_img_path

        # Save the dimensions of the needle image
        self.needle_w = self.needle_img.shape[1]
        self.needle_h = self.needle_img.shape[0]
                                 
    def match_keypoints(self, haystack_screenshot, name, min_match_count, patch_size=32):

        orb = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=patch_size)
        keypoints_needle, descriptors_needle = orb.detectAndCompute(self.needle_img, None)
        orb2 = cv.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, patchSize=patch_size, nfeatures=2000)
        keypoints_haystack, descriptors_haystack = orb2.detectAndCompute(haystack_screenshot, None)

        FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
        index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_LSH, table_number=6, key_size=12, multi_probe_level=1)
        search_params = dict(checks=50)

        try:
            flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
            matches = flann.knnMatch(descriptors_needle, descriptors_haystack, k=2)
        except cv.error:
                return None, None, [], []
            
        # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
        good = []
        points = []

        for pair in matches:
            if len(pair) == 2:
                if pair[0].distance < 0.7*pair[1].distance:
                    good.append(pair[0])

        if len(good) > min_match_count:
            print(str(name) + ' - ' + '%03d keypoints matched - %03d' % (len(good), len(keypoints_needle)))
           
            for match in good:
                points.append(keypoints_haystack[match.trainIdx].pt)
        
        return keypoints_needle, keypoints_haystack, good, points
```

Comment: don't use brute-force, use flann. opencv comes with a sample/tutorial that implements all the usual descriptors combined with flann. you can copy from there. -- try other feature descriptors besides ORB. ORB is not terribly great.

Comment: Stupidly got confused when typing this up, I AM using flann, although I did think it was called ORB brute force flann matching from the tutorial but I think I'm combining the two. I've updated the 3rd code block correctly.

Comment: And to confirm it's the flann section that's taking the longest. I'm using ORB to generate the keypoints. This was all from the tutorial.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz do you think pre-compiling my keypoints on the images I'm looking to detect might speed things up? Only asking because it'll be a not insignificant re-rewrite (for me).